# Log PHP exceptions and Errors to Database table PHP Slim 3

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, slim, slim-3

So I am trying to find the best way to get PHP SLIM 3 to log PHP exceptions and errors to a Database table instead of a log.  whats the best way to accomplish this?  So far in the documentation recommends this.

Dependency:

```
$app = new \Slim\App();
$c = $app->getContainer();
$c['errorHandler'] = function ($c) {
    return function ($request, $response, $exception) use ($c) {
        return $response->withStatus(500)
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            ->write('Something went wrong!');
    };
};
```

What I am having trouble understanding is where do I call this and how could I connect this to log it into a database table that I created.   Any Ideas?

Comment: You don't explicitly call this function, it as automatically called when exceptions occur. You simply write the function in a way you see fit, i.e write it so it is able to log errors in db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this for Slim 3?

```php
$config = [
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,

        'db' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'username' => 'root',
            'database' => 'test',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
           'flags' => [
               PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
           ],
        ]
    ],
];

$app = new \Slim\App($config);

$container = $app->getContainer();

$container[PDO::class] = function ($container) {
    $settings = $container['settings']['db'];

    $host = $settings['host'];
    $dbname = $settings['database'];
    $username = $settings['username'];
    $password = $settings['password'];
    $charset = $settings['charset'];
    $flags = $settings['flags'];
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=$charset";

    return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $flags);
}

$container[PDO::class] = function ($container) {
    $settings = $container['settings']['db'];

    $host = $settings['host'];
    $dbname = $settings['database'];
    $username = $settings['username'];
    $password = $settings['password'];
    $charset = $settings['charset'];
    $flags = $settings['flags'];
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=$charset";

    return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $flags);
};

$container ['errorHandler'] = function ($container ) {
    $connection = container[PDO::class];

    return function ($request, $response, $exception) use ($connection) {

        $row = [
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
        ];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO error_logs SET message=:message";

        $connection->prepare($sql)->execute($row);

        return $response->withStatus(500)
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            ->write('Something went wrong!');
    };
};
```

Comment: Thank you @odan, but, also, how do I call it and where?   would I call this in my try and catch scenarios?

Comment: Like Nima said, you don't have to call it. This callback function is called automatically (by Slim) when an error/exception occurs. Btw: Why don't you use Slim 4?